# How Do I filter this range of multiple rows and columns only by their headers?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range of names with their team names as headers, how do I retrieve the header for a specific persons name?

Pic:

[image]

I have a person's name, and want to find the team they are associated with. how do I do this?

Let's say I have `Name 40` using that, what would I need to do to determine the team it's under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious issue is that a name may not be unique. Below I assume that it is; otherwise my formula won't give a meaningful result, and you will want to use a better identifier than a name.

I will use an [`offset`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en) from the cell with "Team 1". In the example, this cell is A2 but the formula is written to be adaptable to other ranges.

```
=offset(A2, 0, max(arrayformula(if(A3:D50 = "Name 40", column(A2:D)-column(A2), 0))))
```

This formula returns "Team 4". Explanation:

- The `if` statement evaluates to 0 at the cells that do not have the needed name. At the cell with this name, it is equal to the column number minus the column number of A2.
- After taking the maximum, we just have the single number mentioned above
- This number is precisely what is needed for `offset(A2,0,...)` to return the team name.

---

There are other approaches: e.g., join each column into a regular expression `^...|...|...|...$` and test the name against each.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this and just receive an error `A circular dependency was detected` on the `arrayformula`. When breaking it apart, I cannot actually perform a function like: `A3:D50 = "Name 40"`, it always errors out saying `An array value could not be found`. I see what you are doing though, just need to figure out a way to do it where it doesn't error out.

Comment: Circular dependency means you put this formula within the range A3:D50. Either move it elsewhere or use a smaller range.

Comment: The formula is outside of the range, It's in column F (or any other column I may put it in). The formula as a whole always returns `Josh`. If I break it down in an attempt to debug, the `arrayformula` chunk always errors saying `A circular dependency was detected`. If I break that down further, the `A3:D50 = "Name 40"` section always errors out with `An array value could not be found` regardless of the value.

Comment: The comparison of array to a string can't work without arrayformula, so that is not surprising. Try `max(arrayformula(...))` instead of `sum`; this is a bit more robust.

Comment: Oh sweet, after changing that it behaves as expected! Thanks a ton.